# Why does Perl's URI complain "Can't locate object method "host" via package "URI::_generic"'?

Tags: perl, uri, host

HI, im trying to get the host from a url.

```
sub scrape {
my @m_error_array;
my @m_href_array;
my @href_array;
my ( $self, $DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpass, $DBname ) = @_;
my ($dbh, $query, $result, $array);
my $DNS = "dbi:mysql:$DBname:$DBhost:3306";
$dbh = DBI->connect($DNS, $DBuser, $DBpass ) or die $DBI::errstr;
if( defined( $self->{_process_image} ) && ( -e 'href_w_' . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt" ) ) {
    open  ERROR_W, "error_w_" . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt";
    open  M_HREF_W, "m_href_w_" . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt";
    open  HREF_W, "href_w_" . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt";
    @m_error_array = ( split( '|||', <ERROR_W> ) );
    @m_href_array = ( split( '|||', <M_HREF_W> ) );
    @href_array = ( split( '|||', <HREF_W> ) );
    close ( ERROR_W );
    close ( M_HREF_W );
    close ( HREF_W );
}else{
    @href_array = ( $self->{_url} );
}
my $z = 0;
while( @href_array ){
    if( defined( $self->{_x_more} ) && $z == $self->{_x_more} ) {
        last;
    }
    if( defined( $self->{_process_image} ) ) {
        $self->write( 'm_href_w', @m_href_array );
        $self->write( 'href_w', @href_array );
        $self->write( 'error_w', @m_error_array );
    }
    $self->{_link_count} = scalar @m_href_array;
    my $href = shift( @href_array );
    my $info = URI->new($href);
    my $host = $info->host;
    $host =~ s/^www\.//;
    $result = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `". $host ."` (URL) VALUES ('$href')");
    if( ! $result->execute() ){
        $result = $dbh->prepare("CREATE TABLE `" . $host . "` ( `ID` INT( 255 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `URL` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` )) ENGINE = MYISAM ;");
        $result->execute()
    }
    $self->{_current_page} = $href;
    my $response = $ua->get($href);
    my $responseCode = $response->code;
    print $responseCode;
}
```

}

Towards te end the line `my $host = $info->host;` is throwing `Can't locate object method "host" via package "URI::_generic"`

Can anyone explain this?

Regards,

Phil

Comment: When you have a problem, reduce it to the shortest example script that demonstrates the problem. Strip away everything else in your program. Find out which data trigger the problem. Often, by going through that process, you find your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`URI->new` creates instances of a subclass of `URI`, depending on the scheme of the url you give it. Those subclasses might be `URI::http`, `URI::file`, `URI::mailto`, or something completely different. If URI doesn't have a specialized subclass for the kind of url you gave it, it'll create an instance of `URI::_generic`.

Each of those URI subclasses have different methods. `URI::http` happens to have a `host` method, but most others don't. You're calling `->host` on something that isn't a `URI::http` or similar, and therefore doesn't have a `host` method.

You probably expected all the strings you pass to `URI->new` to be http urls. That doesn't seem to be the case, so you might want to check your data. Otherwise, if you do want to handle non-http urls, you should make sure a method actually exists for that instance before calling it, for example by using `->can` or `->isa`.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed reply. I have added `use URI::http;` at the top of the document and changed code to `my $info = URI::http->new($href); my $host = $info->host;` but im still getting the same error.

Comment: `URI::http`, being a subclass of `URI`, as I pointed out, inherits its constructor from `URI`, and therefore also has the scheme-autodetection logic. I recommend you try one of the things I already suggested.

Comment: Sorry, yeah you are correct, there's just something else on top which is helping the outcome (like the $href being 'h'). Cheers

Comment: FWIW, this would be easier to use of the method were defined and returned undef. Having to write guards to protect this everywhere feels an awful lot like Java.

Answer (score 1):

To word this differently - URI attempts to guess the scheme, and if the URL is of a bad format will be of a scheme that doesn't have those methods.

All you need is a check something like:

```
if($uri->scheme ne 'http'){
    die "URL '$url' was not http\n";
}
```

scheme will be there even when it hasn't found a scheme.  It'll just not have a value.